# E-mail sucessfully sent via AJAX POST but error callback triggered instead of success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am sending e-mails using AJAX and It works, e-mails are sent to my recipients. However what I don´t understand is why the AJAX´s `success` callback is not triggered despite an e-mail have been sent. Instead, an `error` callback is triggered.

Apparently it is NOT a CORS issue because I am using the same server in AJAX's `url` parameter. Also Google Dev Tools is not reporting any issues and shows `200 OK`.

**JS code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".js-validate-2").validate({
        ignore: ":hidden",
        rules: {
            //something
        },
        messages: {
            //something
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var recipient = "myEmailTest@gmail.com"
            var specifiedProduct = "PRODUCT: " + $('#specifiedProduct').val();
            var msg = $('#msg').val();
            var phone = "TEL: " + $('#phone').val() + ". ";

            var params = {
                "email": recipient,
                "subject": specifiedProduct,
                "body": msg + phone,
            };

            var sendingToSupport = $.ajax({
                url: 'http://myServer/u/support/message',
                data: JSON.stringify(params),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("Huge success");
                    console.log(params);
                    console.log(data);
                    alert("Successfully sent!");
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log("Huge failure");
                    console.log(params);
                    console.log(data);
                    alert("We apologize for an error!");
                    $(".support-form").find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
                }
            });
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Is the data returned valid json?  `dataType: 'json'` says you expect it to be, and jQuery will try to parse it that way, which if it is not valid, or provided, it will error and run the error callback instead.

Comment: The `error` handler will be triggered if the response HTTP code was not a successful one, ie. outside `status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304`. It will also be fired if the format of the response cannot be deserialised. In your case, that would occur if the response was not valid JSON.

Comment: @Taplar You are right, thanks.

Comment: `: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )` log the errorThrown and it will tell you the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue was caused by following code:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

which says that data returned by AJAX call will be in JSON format. Hence jQuery will try to parse those data.

In my case, deleting this code helped and AJAX call was successfully sent with a proper answer returned.